# Why do we use the term "order" for the cardinality of a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

When we talk about the *order* of an **element** $g$ in a group, we are referring to the minimal integer $n$ such that $g^n=e$.

But then, we start talking about the *order* of a **subgroup**, which is understood to be the size of this subgroup; in other words the cardinality of the subgroup.

If we already have the word "cardinality" to denote the size of a set, why is it that these two words are being mixed together, when there is no relationship between what they mean?

Unless there is, of course, something that I am missing that bridges the gap here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the order of an element is the order of the subgroup it generates, so that's the connection between the two notions. We could just use "cardinality", but if I recall correctly the "order" terminology actually predates the use of the word "cardinality"; also, it doesn't really make sense to speak of the cardinality of an element of a group.